# Select generic ndb Model by id

Tags: app-engine-ndb

The model ids are unique in all clases.
I want to know how to use "get_by_id()" without know the model class name.

For example, in

```
MyModel.get_by_id(42)
```

need to use "MyModel" class

and in this other way

```
ndb.Key(MyModel, id).get()
```

need the class name too.

I think that could be posible something without the class name. I am rigth?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.  First, the auto-assigned IDs are not unique across models.  Second, entities have a "key" that is composed of one or more (model, ID) pairs -- the model (== class name) is an essential part of the key.

You may be confused by queries.  It is possible (though not recommended) to have a query for "all entities", i.e. without specifying the model.  But this will obviously not scale.

Comment: Thanks guido for your fast response.
And thanks too for your excelent work!